# Use Php Variable in Headers From field

Tags: php

Im trying to setup a PHP Mailer.
For some unknown reason i cant use a variable on the From field

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Blaine<{$from_email}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from_email . "" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";
```

Instead of Blaine i would like to use a Variable i set previously, but when i do that like this
Im trying to setup a PHP Mailer.
For some unknown reason i cant use a variable on the From field

```
$headers .= "From: .$var <{$from_email}>\r\n";
```

i get unknown as senders name

Comment: It looks like you are trying to concatenate while inside double quotes. Try `$headers .= 'From: ' . $var . '<' . $from_email . ">\r\n";`.

Comment: Or just skip the "." before `$var`. This will add the dot to the From header, making it not RFC-comform.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers .= "From: $senderName <$senderEmail>\r\n";
```